# Best Guest OS for running FreeSWITCH under Proxmox

Tags: linux, openvz, proxmox, freeswitch

We have a lot of Asterisk systems running on dedicated machines and would like to use FreeSWITCH to replace a number of them. One of the advantages of FreeSWITCH is supposed to be that it is doing much better in a virtualized environment than Asterisk is. However, I can find very little information about people using it in Proxmox containers. I would like to know if anyone has seen any ready to run Proxmox images that include FreeSWITCH so we can test a number of things without having to deeply go into creating our own. Or at least a clue to which system images/distro images we can use to quickly get it installed not having to deal with too many dependency or different Linux version issues.

Just to be clear:
It should be for a more or less current Proxmox and current FreeSWITCH.
I am not looking forward to use the KVM mode but would consider it, if it is otherwise ready to run out of the box. I would rather use a real OpenVZ based container.

Thanks for anyone helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a combination of Debian Linux and XEN virtualization, and they work fine togeth4er. FreeSWITCH team maintains Debian packages, so that you don't need to build from sources. Also XEN hypervisor provides the VM access to hardware clock, which is very important for conferences and transcoding.